# How can I import a conda library into a seperate Spyder distribution?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, spyder

I have recently installed Spyder 2 on my MacBook. Then, since I couldn't import the sklearn library, i decided to also download Anaconda from their Website. Now, Anaconda comes with a Spyder environment itself, on which I can import sklearn, however the IDE is laggy. Is there a way to use the conda sklearn library on my separately downloaded Spyder (which runs much smoother)? Both Spyders are running Python 3.9.5 and I'm using MacOs 10.15.7

I tried setting a path via the PYTHONPATH Manager, but Spyder 2 forbids setting a path to 'site-packages' and after copying sklearn into another folder and setting a path there, import failed:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib'`

I also installed sklearn via pip on the terminal, but I run into the same kind of problems if I try to import sklearn in my seperate Spyder 2('no module named sklearn found' or I can't set a path there or some module is missing).
And if I try to run

`pip install scikit-learn`

in the IPython console directly, I get

`/Applications/Spyder 2.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No module named pip`

while if I try

`conda install scikit-learn`

in the IPython console I get

``` ValueError: The python kernel does not appear to be a conda environment.  Please use ``%pip install`` instead. ```

So I seem to be running in circles...

Answer (score 1):

1. **conda** and **pip** are executables and not to be run from the IPython console, but from a command shell.
2. Don't mix conda and pip installations if you don't have to. Only install scikit-learn with conda.
3. Before you can use any installation, you have to **activate** the base environment first with `conda activate`.
4. There is no shame in reading the documentation first, e.g. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/

Comment: You can run `conda` or `pip` from an `iPython` or `jupyter` console by prepending it with a `!`

Comment: Even though I changed the default environment to conda, restarted the kernel and ran `conda activate`, I still get `ValueError: The python kernel does not appear to be a conda environment.` I do not understand the difference between this and the Spyder started via the Anaconda Navigator, where it works fine. Sadly, the documentation does not help beyond this point.